# Operator '|>' in facebook's Flow

Tags: ocaml

I am new to ocaml, passed a few tutorials and thought that as for next step, I would get familiar with the syntax by reading some OOS. So I downloaded [Flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow) from facebook.

However, I ran into some weird syntax using '|>' that I can't figure out.

First I encountered the "|>" [here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/d7ab6e73df55aef15134b1344afed4747f75e5f9/src/commands/astCommand.ml#L26):

```
  args = CommandSpec.ArgSpec.(
    empty
    |> flag "--tokens" no_arg
        ~doc:"Include a list of syntax tokens in the output"
    |> flag "--pretty" no_arg
        ~doc:"Pretty-print JSON output"
    |> CommandUtils.from_flag
    |> anon "file" (optional string) ~doc:"[FILE]"
  )
```

When I am looking for its definition, I found this in another file:

```
let (|>) (o : 'a)  (f : 'a -> 'b) : 'b = f o
```

But I am not quite sure what it's doing or if it's even related.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let (|>) (o : 'a)  (f : 'a -> 'b) : 'b = f o
```

This is declaring an infix operator called `|>`, which you know is infix because of the parens around the name.

It takes two arguments, `o` with an unknown type `'a`, and `f` which is a function from `'a` to a second unknown type `'b`.

`|>` returns something of type `'b`.

The result is computed by `f o`.

In other words, `o |> f` is the same as `f o`.  This is just a dirty / neat trick to be able to write the argument declarations in a chain this way, without having to put lots of parentheses around everything.  The operator has low precedence so it acts as a separator between each flag declaration.

Comment: 'which you know is inline': is that the same as 'infix' in other languages?

Comment: The correct word is infix, the answer should be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

It's a (forward) pipe operator.

Rather than invoking functions where it's in the form:

```
f arg
```

The pipe operator allows you to invoke it as:

```
arg |> f
```

This makes chaining function calls significantly easier to both read and write.

```
arg |> f |> g |> h
```

vs

```
h (g (f arg))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pipe operator
It allows to apply a sequence of function quite easily :
f(g(h x)) can be written x |> h |> g |> f.

Its declaration, using parenthesis, says it is an infix operator :
x |> f means  f x.